# Reset SQL Server execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I've looked all over for this command....what's the command to reset the SQL Server's execution plan?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For clarity..........

Executing `sp_recompile` will "mark" the given stored procedure for recompilation, which will occur the next time it is executed.

Using the `WITH RECOMPILE` option will result in a new execution plan being generated each time the given stored procedure is executed.

To clear the entire procedure cache execute

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Comment: Can DBCC FREEPROCCACHE be executed just for a specific procedure?

Comment: @CodeMilan: Yes you can evict a specific plan_handle (the query plan for a given stored procedure for example) from the plan/procedure cache. See BOL for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx

Answer (score 5):

For stored procedures, you use the `WITH RECOMPILE` option.

Comment: +1 AHA !! Now things begin to make sense :-) You're better at deciphering unclear user messages, I must see...

Comment: Please notes that this method will recompile the given stored procedure each and every time it is executed, so if you wish to just force a one off recompile then use the system stored procedure sp_recompile.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reset QEP for a stored procedure, you shall use [`sp_recompile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you're after. But in addition to the other suggestions, DBCC FREEPROCCACHE clears all cached execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

sp_recompile will dump the existing query plan and recompile the procedure.
Or you can restart SQL and that will clear the entire execution plan cache.

WITH RECOMPILE is going to generate a new plan EVERY time you execute it.

Comment: A small but important distinction, executing sp_recompile will not recompile a given stored procedure but will instead mark it for recompilation the next time it is executed.